# Jquery in Reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I am using materialize CSS in react js but i'm facing a problem right now because some of the CSS components needs Jquery to be initialize or animate.So is it fine to use jquery in react js and how can i use it in the React component.

Comment: Answering specific to your question description, it would be a good practice to add it in index.html file of your react app below the body tag. (like how you would add it in typical html file)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [Integrating other libraries in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

You can do like this

```
class SomePlugin extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.$el = $(this.el);    this.$el.somePlugin();  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.$el.somePlugin('destroy');  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => this.el = el} />;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first up, jQuery is no longer a dependency of Materialize (hasn't been since 2017):

https://medium.com/@materializecss/materialize-to-1-0-and-beyond-e0233b8ac15

To initialise any component with vanilla JS, check the component page. For instance, for the [carousel](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems);
  });
```

Further reading: A [good article](https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9) on using JS at component level.